# I have just started learning redux and I need some help how to remove an item from the state array

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a list of song that when clicked a button shows the details. Now I want on click of another button to remove the details shown. The function is removeDescriptionReducer. Im am showing my reducers file.

reducers.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const songsReducer = () =>{
  return [
    { title: 'No Scrubs', duration: '4:05'},
    { title: 'Macarena', duration: '3:55'},
    { title: 'All Stars', duration: '1:28'},
    { title: 'I want it that way', duration: '2:05'},

  ];
};



const selectedSongReducer = (selectedSong=null, action) => {

  if(action.type === 'SONG_SELECTED'){
    return action.payload;
  }

  return selectedSong;

}



const removeDescriptionReducer = (removeDescription=null, action) => {

    if(action.type === 'REMOVE_DESCRIPTION'){
    alert (action.payload);
  }

  return removeDescription;

}

export default combineReducers({
  songs: songsReducer,
  selectedSong: selectedSongReducer,
  removeDescription: removeDescriptionReducer
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide further input on what you are receiving in the payload and what do you want exactly, you want to return a new state with all entries (songs) except the one clicked on or something else?

Answer (score 0):

As per the question title, you want to remove an item from the state:

```
return state.filter(elem => elem.title == 'xyx')
```

or

```
return state.filter(elem => elem.title == payload.title)
```

this will return all the elems except the one which matches the condition specified

where xyz can be the title in the payload

in your code:

```
const removeDescriptionReducer = (removeDescription = null, action) => {

  if (action.type === 'REMOVE_DESCRIPTION') {
    alert(action.payload);
    return songsReducer.filter(song => song.title == action.payload.title);
  }

  return removeDescription;

}
```

**Also, don't want to discourage you, but your reducer must look like this:**

```
const songs = () => {
  return [{
      title: 'No Scrubs',
      duration: '4:05'
    },
    {
      title: 'Macarena',
      duration: '3:55'
    },
    {
      title: 'All Stars',
      duration: '1:28'
    },
    {
      title: 'I want it that way',
      duration: '2:05'
    },

  ];
};


const songsReducer = (state = songs, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ALL_SONGS':
      return state;
    case 'SONG_SELECTED':
      return action.payload;
    case 'REMOVE_DESCRIPTION':
        return state.filter(song => song.title == action.payload.title);
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

*and thus you don't need to create different reducers for performing different operations.*